# Owlcarousel2 - how to check the last item

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel-2

How do I check the last item? in version 1 had the function "maximumItem"

```
afterAction: function () {
if (this.currentItem == this.maximumItem) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".owl-carousel").on('initialized.owl.carousel changed.owl.carousel refreshed.owl.carousel', function (e) {
    if (!e.namespace) return;
    var carousel = e.relatedTarget,
        current = carousel.current();
    if (current === carousel.maximum()) {
      ...
    }
});
```